# How to file a bug report for avahi-autoipd.action

Tags: avahi

Does anyone know how to file a bug report for `/etc/avahi/avahi-autoipd.action`

it comes in the the package

avahi-autoipd

but I'm not sure if this script is avahi devs or Ubuntu.  The script is called by avahi but I'm not sure if its written by them.

Bug is that it tacks `:avahi` on to the interface name and the exceeds the 15 char limit.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=avahi-daemon;dist=unstable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

reportbug errored end led me to

```
ubuntu-bug avahi-autoipd
```

Which seemed to do the trick